# How to get a redirected link with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Given an array/list of URLs when iterating each link and opening each one up.
I came across an issue which is, that some links like https://someLink.com/ONE
get's redirected to https://someLink.com/TWO
when clicked.

I iterate each link in my array and open it in the browser using 
"window.open()" function. 
and I want each link to be the last possible link, which means no redirections after I clicked.

```
document.getElementById("someBtnId").onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (let i = 0; i < urlLinks.length; i++) {
        window.open(urlLinks[i]); // here I want to open the real link.
    }
};
```

The catch is that I want to achieve this using only vanilla java script (if that's even possible).

EDIT: 
basically I want some button to open all the links I have in some arbitrary array (when clicked).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a name to each window that you open

```
window.open(urlLinks[i], `Name${i}`);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open